# SVG rotate text with % as Unit

Tags: svg, rotation, transform

I try to rotate a svg text. i get the position of the text as % i.e. 15% by calling a php function from xslt. the problem is that i can not rotate a svg object using %. it works if i use a digit number instead.
Below i present the problem as simplified:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://ww.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
  <text x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(-90 50% 50%)">rotateMe</text>
  <line x1="50%" y1="47%" x2="60%" y2="47%" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px"/>
</svg>
```

this pic is in the middle of my browser screen
[image: The initial point]

And i want that it looks like this:
[image: The goal]

but it dont work because of %

```
transform="rotate(-90 **50% 50%**)"
```

it is a requirement for me to use % for the coordinates. Any ideas or solution to my problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate the co-ordinates using an inner `<svg>` element. The example below displays as per your "i want that it looks like this" bitmap on Firefox.

If you can't see the text on whatever browser you are using, try adding overflow="visible" to the inner `<svg>` element so you can see where it ends up. Not all browsers support the dominant-baseline attribute so you may need to fiddle about with the text's y attribute instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="100" height="100">
      <text text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" transform="rotate(-90 0 0)">rotateMe</text>
  </svg>
  <line x1="50%" y1="47%" x2="60%" y2="47%" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works:) the reason why i want to rotate text is because of a x axis caption. in thanks of your answer i can rotate the text. but i caption the xaxis in a for-each statement and it looks like a little weak curve at the x axis caption. the back labels are slightly higher than the one before.:( Any ideas why this can happen???