# Rotate text in SVG

Tags: xml, svg, rotation, scale, scaletransform

I got a chart with svg which looks like [image: Chart]

Now I want to rotate the text like [image: Chart]

My `SVG root` is the following

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
    viewbox="-75 0 1075 800"
    transform="translate(0, 750) scale(1, -1)"
    width="1000" height="800">
</svg>
```

If I try to rotate the text with

```
<text x="-70" y="50%" stroke="blue" transform="rotate(90)">U [mV]</text>
```

the text disappears.

With

```
<text x="-70" y="50%" stroke="blue" transform="rotate(90 -70 50%)">U [mV]</text>
```

nothing happens.

What have I to do to rotate the three text objects shown in the second picture? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure 100% what's going on, but I suspect it's 'rotating' around the wrong point, and the text ends up in a different place, probably off screen in your first case. Try rotating by just 1, and seeing if it moves slightly- that might give you some indication of exactly what's happening.

Comment: `transform` attributes in svg don't support percentage values (yet), they will hopefully do so in the future. A fiddle might be good, but your problem is very likely due to the flipped coordinate system, and there are several ways to fix that.

Comment: There is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12109483/4235784) to a similar problem which should also work for you. This in particular addresses using rotations on an element which is positioned by some percentage. If you are not bound to positioning by `50%` as a relative value, there are easier solutions to it. In that case be a bit more specific and provide some more code to get a good answer.

Comment: Another side note, although this is not directly related to your problem: There is a flaw in your `<svg>` root element. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement) it does not support the `transform` attribute. Although some user agents might render it correctly you should probably insert a `<g>` and apply the transformation on that to be fully compliant with the spec.

Comment: The hint with the `<g>`-Tag from @altocumulus was good (with the `<svg>`-Tag it should similar work). If I use it for my text object, too, I could define a new coordinate system for this object and rotate to the point of origin (it was the wrong point from which I wanted to rotate like in the comment from @Flynn1179 said).

Comment: If this solved your problem please consider writing an answer to your own question to share your solution with the rest of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me now:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
    viewbox="-75 0 1075 800"
    width="1000" height="800">

    <g transform="translate(0, 750) scale(1, -1)"> <!-- hint from @altocumulus -->
        ...

        <g transform="translate(-75, 375) scale(1, -1) rotate(-90)">
            <!--
                translate(x, y) => create a new local coordination system
                with the point of origin at this point
            -->

            <text stroke="blue">U [mV]</text>
        </g>

        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```